# .htaccess need rewrite rule and extra query string

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have the following line in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^newpdfs/(.*)\.pdf /getnewpdf.php?pdf=$1
```

`getnewpdf.php` is a script for adding the name of a user from a session to the filename that gets downloaded. However, there is a scenario where the session hasn't been created and the user's name needs to come from a database. So I need to pass an ID (when needed). I have this:

```
RewriteRule ^newpdfs/(.*)\.pdf?id=(.*) /getnewpdf.php?pdf=$1&id=$2
```

However my ID query is getting ignored. How would I go about passing a query string too?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `L` (Last) flag and you will need QSA (Query String Append) to append any existing query string. Over your code should be like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^newpdfs/([^.]+)\.pdf$ /getnewpdf.php?pdf=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `QSA` flag to your existing rule:

```
RewriteRule ^newpdfs/(.*)\.pdf /getnewpdf.php?pdf=$1 [QSA]
```

When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

Further reference here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 1):

Add [QSA] to the end of the rule it means to append the query string